# Storing and getting boolean with Redis

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I'm trying to use Redis to store and get a boolean for my toggle function.

The dependecy what I'm using is `redis-js` I can set the value `false` with key to redis but getting the valu from redis is always `false`.

Say first store the key value to Redis

```
redis.set('myKey', 'false');
```

Get the value

```
let toggle = redis.get('myKey');
toggle = !toggle;
```

Store

```
redis.set('myKey', toggle);
```

Get

```
const checkStatus = redis.get('myKey');
return checkStatus;
```

I'm expecting the output will be `true -> false` if executed the function two times.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For your toogle to work you've to explicitly check if the value you get is equal to the string `'false'`.

```
let toggle = redis.get('myKey');
toggle = toogle === 'false'
```

Converting the string `'false'` to boolean results to `true` **not** `false` and negating it you get `false`.

From MDN

> All other values, including any object or the string `"false"`, create an object with an initial value of `true`

Here's an illustration:

```js
const val = 'false'

const toggle = !val; // this is equivalent to !Boolean(val)

const bool = Boolean(val) // get boolean
const negated = !bool // negate
console.log('toggle: ', toggle);
console.log('bool: ', bool); // Boolean("false") gives true
console.log('negated: ', negated);
```

Answer (score 3):

You run command redis.get, the return value type is String not Boolean.

So you should't use ! operator, you can compare with 'true' or 'false', then assign a value